# Debian: Removing read permissions to a single user

Tags: linux, chmod

i'm trying to set permissions with `chmod` in Debian Squeeze.

Its there any way to remove read permission to a single specified user?

```
chmod u-r file
```

That seems to deny permissions from the user invokating the command only. Is there a way to specify a user or group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `acls`, that's what you want, if you need to edit rights to specific users without messing up with lots of standard linux groups.

Use `mount`, to see if there is option `acl` at your mount points.

Or try running `getfacl yourfile`, if this works than you are already using `acls` and you can add rights to more than one specific user by `setfacl`.

Here you can find nice backround to acls: http://users.suse.com/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/

Comment: After 5+ years, this link is dead. Archive: http://archive.is/el8gM

Answer (score 0):

File level permisions will be tied to owner, group, and world.  Unless you want to change the owner of the file (`chown`), you can't do anything user wise.

The u flag for `chmod` is actually the owner of the file.  You can use g instead to change the group permissions, e.g. `chmod g-r file`

Alternatively, you can use the [numeric mode](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html#hownum) to change permissions for owner, group, and world all at once.

Relatedly, if you want to only have certain users access the file, you may need to create a new group (`groupadd`) and then change the group on the file using `chgrp`.